# how to get child xml block as text using rapidxml

Tags: xml, rapidxml

I want to get child xml block  as text. Example.

My xml like this;

```
<message>
....

<data>
  <name> John </name> <age> 17 </age>
<data>

....
<message>
```

How to get <`name> John </name> <age> 17 </age>`  as text....

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Use `print` function on the node.

http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#namespacerapidxml_1printing